# Why DataFrame columns must be unique for json convert?

Tags: python, pandas

After combining two dataframes, I have this dataframe:

```
ip                 accountname      name      gsm
192.168.1.1        aaaa             john doe  850
192.168.1.2        bbbb             jane doe  860
```

I want to convert dataframe to json:

```
json_df = df3.set_index('ip').T.to_json()
```

And I have :

```
ValueError: DataFrame columns must be unique for orient='columns'.
```

IPs are unique in dataframe. Index column is unique. How can I avoid this error? any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is same as `df.set_index('ip').to_json(orient='index')`. Are you sure `ip` column is unique?

Comment: @Zero yes, ip is unique

Comment: You shouldn't be getting this ValueError if the `ip`s are unique. You can verify that the `ip`s are unique by inspecting  `df3.set_index('ip').index.is_unique`. If it returns False, then that explains the error. If it returns True, then you need to [file a bug report](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) (with a runnable example that reproduces the problem.)

Comment: To help us reproduce the problem, post `df3.to_dict('list')`.

Comment: Or, you could avoid the error by using `to_json(orient='split')`...

Comment: @unutbu values of ip are unique. But df3.set_index('ip').index.is_unique is false

Comment: @unutbu   `to_json(orient='split')` has a result that I don't want. I need something like `{'192.168.1.1':{`'accountname ':'aaaa', 'name':'john doe', 'gsm':'850'}}

Comment: How do you know they are unique? Have you checked it with `.duplicated` method.

Comment: Can you show the output of `k = df['ip'].value_counts()`  then `k[k>1]`

Comment: is `ip` still index? Then `df.reset_index()['ip'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

If `df3.set_index('ip').index.is_unique` is false, it means you have duplicated ip, probably due to a previous merge.

If you don't care about the duplicates you can use `to_json(orient='records')`

Answer (score 0):

I was puzzled by the same thing. As "saccodd" suggests I used:

```
df.index.is_unique
```

and the answer was "True".

However, upon inspection of the names of my columns:

```
for col in df.columns: 
    print(col)
```

I got:

```
Area
Month
2019
2020
2019
2020
```

In other words, I had 2 columns with the name "2019" and 2 columns with the name "2020".

In other words: the column names were not unique (which is what the error message actually says, to the letter ...).

In my case this was due to a query like:

```
select Area, 
       parking_month as Month, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN parking_year = 2019 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as "2019",
       SUM(CASE WHEN parking_year = 2020 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as "2020",
       SUM(CASE WHEN parking_year = 2019 THEN seconds ELSE 0 END) as "2019",
       SUM(CASE WHEN parking_year = 2020 THEN seconds ELSE 0 END) as "2020",
from some_parking_data
```

changing this query to:

```
select Area, 
       parking_month as Month, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN parking_year = 2019 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as "A2019",
       SUM(CASE WHEN parking_year = 2020 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as "A2020",
       SUM(CASE WHEN parking_year = 2019 THEN seconds ELSE 0 END) as "T2019",
       SUM(CASE WHEN parking_year = 2020 THEN seconds ELSE 0 END) as "T2020",
from some_parking_data
```

solved the issue.